# How do I convert a word document to Daisy Format

Tags: audio, microsoft-word, conversion, format

I have been looking at getting a daisy converted but all I can see is going to cost me over a grand. Do you know of any way that I can do it cheaper than that?

Comment: Have you tried the trial version of EasyConverter, which is linked from the Daisy web site?

Comment: Also, questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

A search resulted in what appears to be plenty of information on the [Daisy Consortium](http://www.daisy.org) web site to help you with this.

Here is some information about an "add-in" for Word to convert to Daisy format and instructions how to do it.

[Microsoft Word Add-in Version 2.5.5.1 for Word 2003, 2007 and Word 2010 (December 2011)](http://www.daisy.org/project/save-as-daisy-microsoft-word-add-in)

[Convert a Word document into a DTBook](http://www.daisy.org/daisypedia/convert-word-document-dtbook)